# Simplifying Rational Expressions in a Finite Field Extension

Tags: roots, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

In Dummit and Foote's textbook one of the exercises is:

> Let $\theta$ be a root of $x^3-2x-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Compute $\frac{1+\theta}{1+\theta+\theta^2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$.

My approach was to look at $\theta^{-1}$: The polynomial gives:
$$\theta^3-2\theta-2=0$$
$$2\theta^{-1}=\theta^2-2$$
Then I changed the expression to be simplified and substituted:
$$\frac{1+\theta}{1+\theta+\theta^2}=\frac{2\theta^{-1}+2}{2\theta^{-1}+2+2\theta}$$
$$=\frac{\theta^2-2+2}{\theta^2-2+2+2\theta}$$
$$=\frac{\theta^2}{\theta^2+2\theta}$$
$$=\frac{\theta}{\theta+2}$$
And then I divided $\theta+2$ into $\theta^3-2\theta-2$ and scaled it to get:
$$(\theta+2)^{-1}=\frac{1}{6}(\theta^2-2\theta+2)$$
And substituted that to get:
$$\theta\frac{1}{6}(\theta^2-2\theta+2)$$
$$\frac{\theta^3-2\theta^2+2\theta}{6}$$
$$\frac{-\theta^2+2\theta+1}{3}$$

I have two questions: How do I know if this the right answer, and is there a less convoluted way to do this?

Comment: If you just want to know if your answer is correct or not, I say your answer is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $x^3-3x-2$ is ireducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ we have
g.c.d of $x^3-3x-2$ with $1+x+x^2$ is $1$ i.e., there exists
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that 
$$f(x)(x^3-3x-2)+g(x)(x^2+x+1)=1$$

Then, See that $\theta^3-3\theta-2=0$ so, we have $g(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta^2+\theta+1}$..

Then multiply by $1+\theta$ to get the required answer..

Comment: So then my answer would be $g(\theta)(1+\theta)$? How do I find $g(\theta)$?

Comment: Set $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $g(x)=mx+n$ and solve for $m,n$